# extract characters between parenthesis with conditions

Tags: python, jython

```
a = '{a=[],b=[],c=[ab=cd,ef=gh],d=[ij=kl],e=[]}'
```

How can I extract characters between parenthesis **[ ]** from above string that are after **=**. 
Output expected is:

```
'cd','gh','kl'
```

Comment: You'd need a regex or you need to find the contents in between the `[` and `]`, split by `=` and take the items from `[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex to capture the string in `[]` with `=` between

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'\w+=(\w+)', a)
```

`\w+` will match all `word` with length 1 or more

`()` denote a capturing group

Comment: And what if I want the output like  ['ab=cd','ef=gh','ij=kl']